# Why FILE * does not store the address of an open file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * Openfile(char *filename,char *mode, FILE *fp);

int main(){

    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char *filename = "simple_index.file";
    char *openmode = "w";

    printf("FP(before call function):%p\n", fp);
    FILE *newfp = Openfile(filename, openmode, fp);
    printf("FP(after call function): %p\nNEWFP: %p\n", fp, newfp);                  

    return 0;
}

FILE * Openfile(char *filename,char *mode, FILE *fp){
    printf((fp = fopen(filename, mode)) ? "Good opening %s file\n": "Error open %s file\n", filename);          
    return fp;

}
```

Result:

```
FP(before call function):0x0
Good opening simple_index.file file
FP(after call function): 0x0
NEWFP: 0x800bc7140
```

A pointer to the file structure does not store the address of an open file after using a function to open a file in the call `Openfile()` function.

Why does `FP` not save the state after use in function? Why need back for save?

Comment: Do you expect that `fx(2); printf("%d\n", 2);` to print `4` after `int fx(int a) { a = 4; return 4; }`?

Comment: That's not how functions work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because `C` uses pass-by-value for function argument passing.

If you want to make changes to a variable passed as an argument to a function from that function itself, you'll be needing a pointer to that variable to be passed to the function and inside the function, you can modify the value pointed by the pointer and in the caller, it will persist.

Otherwise, to get the value back from the called function, usually we `return` the value and assign it to the variable in the caller function.

Answer (score 5):

`fopen` stores the updated pointer but to access that you need to provide the address of the pointer.

Try with:

```
FILE *newfp = Openfile(filename, openmode, &fp);

FILE * Openfile(char *filename,char *mode, FILE **fp){
    printf((*fp = fopen(filename, mode)) ? "Good opening %s file\n": "Error open %s file\n", filename);          
    return *fp;

}
```

Now `*fp`and `newfp` will print the same value

Answer (score 2):

Change the function to this:

```
FILE * Openfile(char *filename,char *mode, FILE **fpp){
    printf((*fpp = fopen(filename, mode)) ? "Good opening %s file\n": "Error open %s file\n", filename);          
    return *fpp;

}
```

And then call it like this:

```
FILE *newfp = Openfile(filename, openmode, &fp);
```